# Why is there "t=[your device]" in duckduckgo query URL?

Tags: url, duckduckgo

I was just searching something on my raspberrypi via duckduckgo and realized that there is `q=[my query]&t=raspberrypi&[rest of the URL]` in the URL bar.
When i did the same query on my PC, there was `...t=h_...`.

Their motto is "We don't track you" so why they need to now what device am I using? The results are the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [DuckDuckGo's &t= page](https://duck.co/help/privacy/t):

> Through [partnerships](https://duck.co/help/company/partnerships) with developers and companies, DuckDuckGo has been integrated into many applications. In these partnerships, a portion of DuckDuckGo's advertising revenue is sometimes shared back. To assign advertising revenue and collect anonymous aggregate usage information, developers add a unique "&t=" parameter to searches made through their applications.

They say the results are an "anonymous aggregate" and not for customizing results or tracking users.

Their [API docs](https://duckduckgo.com/api) also suggest apps using the API should include a descriptive `t` parameter.

> Use a descriptive t parameter, i.e. append &t=nameofapp to your requests.

Sounds like whatever software you are using on your Raspberry Pi is simply using this feature as instructed.

Comment: So basically it's for partner's statistics ? It only record what kind of device is used and no more

Comment: @Walfrat I don't think i t is meant to record the device necessarily, just whatever app name was supplied.

Comment: So basically what does that mean ? Considering we're a bit (or totally :p ) paranoïac. That can mean that duckduckgo could gather for an IP (which is probably not fixed for a mobile) what is all the app on that device that query him ?

Comment: @Walfrat No, it's just for the anonymous statistics. It does not necessarily even contain the name of the device, `raspberrypi` is just what the developer used to identify their usage to DDG. If DDG wanted to secretly track users, this string would not be very useful and they could be much more secretive about it.